# Segmentation fault in strcpy or anything to do with reading certain variable

Tags: c, unix, memory, codeblocks

```
char *multi_tok(char *input, int *type) {
    static char *string;
    if (input != NULL)
        string = input;

    if (string == NULL)
        return string;

    char *end=NULL;
    for(int i=0; *(string+i+1) != 0; i++)
    {
        if( *(string+i) == '|')
        {
            *type=0;
            end=(string+i);
            break;
        }else if( *(string+i) == '<')
        {
            *type=1;
            end=(string+i);
            break;
        }else if( *(string+i) == '>' && *(string + i + 1) == '>'){
            *type=2;
            end=(string+i);
            break;
        }
        else if( *(string+i) == '>'){
            *type=3;
            end=(string+i);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(end==NULL)
    {
        char *temp=string;
        string =NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    *end='\0';
    char *temp;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(string));
    strcpy(temp, string);
    int d=(*type != 2) ? 2 : 3 ;
    string=end + d;
    return temp;
}


int main (int argc, char* argv [])
{
  char cmdline[BUFSIZ];
  for(;;) {
    printf("COP4338$ ");
    if(fgets(cmdline, BUFSIZ, stdin) == NULL) {
      perror("fgets failed");
      exit(1);
    }
    int *type;
    char *str= multi_tok(cmdline, type);
    int i=0;
    char str_c[1024];
    while (str != NULL) {
        strcpy(str_c, str);
        str = multi_tok(NULL, type);
        }
    }
}
```

The segmentation occurs around:

```
while (str != NULL) {
        strcpy(str_c, str);
        str = multi_tok(NULL, type);
        }
    }
```

or pretty much anything to do with reading variable **str**  even if I don't use strcpy and manual loop to copy the string seg fault occurs any way. However If I build a function to copy the string it works for example:

```
char *copy(char *str)
{
    char *str2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str));
    strcpy(str2, str);
    return str2;
}
...
while (str != NULL) {
    str_c=copy(str);
    str = multi_tok(NULL, type);
    }
}
...
//works
```

Why it this happening?

Comment: It's off-by-one error. `char *str2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str));` --> `char *str2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Don't cast `void *`.

Comment: for(int i=0; *(string+i+1) != 0; i++)  Why +1?  This +1 can create out of 
 array bound situation.

Comment: woah! Thank you! such an small error and cause such a big headache.

Comment: yes the loop that I did was for(int i=0; *(string+i) != 0; i++), still the loop should stop when *(string+i)=='\0' why would this cause seg fault?

Comment: `int *type;
    char *str= multi_tok(cmdline, type);` --> `int type;
    char *str= multi_tok(cmdline, &type);` (Pras pointed out)

Comment: @Yumario - Yes.  You are right!!! It should stop.  That should be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type is not allocated any memory to it, so assigning *type=0 would lead to possible segmentation failt